# How to save/load an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to save an ArrayList (That contains Strings).
When I click the "Save" button it should save it and when I click the "Load" button it should load it.

I just have this for now :

```
            aff.getButtonSave().addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ // aff = contains the display
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            //We check if we have at least one rule into the arraylist
            try {
                if(!rules.getListeRules().isEmpty()) {
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));                   
                        pw.println(rules.toStringList()); //toStringList Returns a string of characters composed of each rule
                    } else {
                    writeHistorique("No rules found.."); //Writing inside the JScrollPane "Historique"
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

For the save one, I also tried but can't figure it out..

Cordially

Comment: what is _aff_? what is _regles_? What does _writeHistorique_ do?

Comment: What is `regles`? What does `toStringList()` return? It that really the file content you want? Can you parse that back? Where *specifically* are you stuck?

Comment: Oups sorry guys, French is my native language, I'm going to post all the correct information. Sorry !

Comment: i can't post all the code because its a project, I never did an load/save things, even at school, I don't know how to proper save an arraylist into a file, and then load it, and those 2 things thanks to 2 buttons. I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I'll do my best..

Comment: We don't need all the code, just a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

A.Arthur,

You are probably looking for something like this?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LoadSaveList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add("Line " + i);
        }
        saveList(list);
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        readList(newList);
        System.out.println(newList);
    }

    private static void readList(List<String> list) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("output.txt"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                list.add(line);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void saveList(List<String> list) {
        FileWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
            for (String str : list) {
                writer.write(str + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```